# How to install openvpn on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I went the the connection manager, then clicked on the VPN tab, but the `add` button is disabled. What should I do? I cannot connected to the internet without the VPN turned on. I'm trying to install openvpn as a client. I already have the `ca.crt` and the `client.conf` with me and currently connected thanks to windows xp.

Comment: You probably need to install [network-manager-openvpn-gnome](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager-openvpn-gnome) off line along with its dependencies. Not sure how doable that is in Lubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commented suggestion works.  Install network-manager-openvpn-gnome and its dependencies.  If you cannot connect to the internet without the vpn, you will have to get them from Ubuntu's repositories through another computer.  Start here http://packages.ubuntu.com/  Then select your version and search for the package by the above name.  When I installed it on Lubuntu 12.10, it required 4 other packages.  Make sure you download those as well, and install them first.  You can install the .deb files from a command line using (trying to run them from a file manager might work as well):

```
sudo deb -i packagefile.deb
```

If you can find the dependency order of all of those packages, then install them in an order such that no package is installed before a package that it is dependent on.  This will make things much simpler.

Comment: Actually, you might also consider using vpnc.  It is a command line vpn program that is fairly easy to use.  If nothing else, it might be worth installing vpnc, which did not have any dependencies for me, to get onto the vpn, so you will have internet access to install network-manager-openvpn-gnome more easily.